# Strange SQL generated from LINQ when checking BIT column

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have the following LINQtoSQL statement

```cs
from t1 in __table1
join t2 in __table2 on t1.Id equals t2.OtherTableId
where t2.BranchId == branchId
      && !t1.IsPersonal
select t1.Id
```

And this generates the following SQL

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[Id]
FROM [__table1] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [__table2] AS [t1] ON [t0].[Id] = [t1].[OtherTableId]
WHERE ([t1].[BranchId] = @p0) AND (NOT ([t0].[IsPersonal] = 1))
```

Now the issue that I have is this:

```sql
(NOT ([t0].[IsPersonal] = 1))
```

How can I write the LINQ to just say

```sql
[t0].[IsPersonal] = 0
```

NOTE: `IsPersonal` is not nullable.

Comment: What happens if you use `t1.IsPersonal == false` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell it produces the same SQL

Comment: Before worrying too much, have you tested the TSQL with tools like SSMS query plan etc to see whether it actually *matters*?

Comment: @MarcGravell it may not matter in the actual execution as the optimiser will probably handle it but I do not like relying in the optimiser. I would also like to understand why it is doing what it is doing.

Comment: I agree it is an interesting curiosity. Frankly, though, I know of only one way to get reliable TSQL that looks the way you want it to look, and doesn't change randomly between versions (whether backend server versions or library versions) - and that is: to write the TSQL yourself.

Comment: @MarcGravell It does matter unfortunately. With the generated `NOT ([t0].[IsPersonal] = 1)` it's a clustered index scan, with `([t0].[IsPersonal] = 0)` it's a non clustered index seek.

Comment: It also matters if you have a filtered index which doesn't allow `NOT = 1`

Comment: BTW this doesn't even work if you create a function `GetFalse => DateTime.Now.Year == 2000` which was my attempt to create a dynamic parameterized value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right so I think that I have figured it out. The following line

```
t1.IsPersonal == false
```

gets optimised as

```
!t1.IsPersonal
```

Which is, in turn, literally translated into

```
(NOT ([t0].[IsPersonal] = 1))
```

Seems that the optimiser is to "blame"

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I may have outsmarted the optimizer but unfortunately when using Linq2Sql the filtered indexes aren't used when the 'filter criteria' is a parameter - which is what this does. So in the end I gave up and switched to a stored procedure. Alternatives were just too icky.

Note: the generated SQL *does* work with filtered indexes without an index hint, but since I was running in in SSMS the query plan cache doesn't apply.

---

Aha! Finally managed to outsmart the optimizer.

`WHERE object.Equals(t.Voided, 0)`  or

`WHERE object.Equals(t.Voided, "false")`

Which generates

`WHERE ([t0].[Voided] = @p0)`

`@p0` is sent as a string or number which SQL Server casts to a boolean for you.

This seems to work with a filtered index (and force hint), which is the reason I needed to get around the optimizer in the first place.

Note: For some reason sometimes `"0"` gives a boolean parse error so `0` or `"false"` is probably better. Could depend on some subtleties of your query.

I prefer `0` because `"false"` ends up being a `varchar(8000)` which is a little overkill!

Comment: Note that `object.Equals(t.Voided, 0)` cannot be substituted for `!t.Voided` in regular code; this is a hack specific for EntityFramework