# TSQL BIT =0 and <>1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bit

Are there any differences if I write

```
select * from table where bit_field = 0
```

or

```
select * from table where bit_field <> 1
```

?

UPDATE:
I've got a report that it is better to use "bit_field = 0" version because if you have some indexes on a field an use the second option there is some issue with "Seek Predicates"... It has two seek predicates one with < 1 and other with > 1... or something. 
I don't have any example to show. :(
After the change from <> to =, there is a decrease of exclusive locks (X) and intent exclusive locks (IX)
Any thoughts on that?

Comment: If the type of the column is bit, then there is no difference

Comment: BIT can be 1, 0 or NULL & given that NULL is excluded by all equality operators there is no difference.

Comment: Logically these is no difference. Practically [there might be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079416/strange-sql-generated-from-linq-when-checking-bit-column#comment75367970_23079416).

Comment: The first one is clearer.

Comment: if one has better performance, then the query optimiser designers will probably have done it for you internally already

Comment: @Kiki . . . An index on a  single `bit` field is generally not recommended (not sufficiently selective).  Indexing might be an issue if you have other equality conditions, with certain indexes, but that would not relate to your particular `where` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no difference, because a bit only takes on the values of 0 and 1.

Both will exclude `NULL` values.

Comment: An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL.

Comment: @TaPaKaHUA `Both will exclude NULL values`

Comment: 'only takes on the values of 0 and 1.'

Comment: I wonder if `<>` is the same as `not(=)`, because if it is, it should cause the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079416/strange-sql-generated-from-linq-when-checking-bit-column#comment75367970_23079416).

Comment: <> => @a > Value AND @a < Value index work only up to the first inequality. Well, it's very short to describe :)

Answer (score 1):

There should be no differences between the two queries.  If there are no `NULL` values present, then obviously any value which is zero is also the same thing as not being one.  If there *are* `NULL`s present, it doesn't change anything, because a `NULL` record would not be returned from either query.

See the demo below.

### Demo